# Can i apply an external css file only to a div and its children?

Tags: css

I don't think it is possible, but I will ask anyway:

**Can I apply an external css file (Bootstrap for instance) to a div and its children without affecting the rest of the page.**

For example, I need to migrate a footer written with Bootstrap over to an existing page.  That page does not use bootstrap. If I link Bootstraps css at the top of the page, the css is applied to the whole page which ruins existing css.  How can I just apply the bootstrap styles to the footer section without having to rewrite most of the page's css?

Any suggestions?

---

I ended up using LESS to compile a new css of bootstrap with a prefix of `.bootstrap` as seen below.  It works, but i wonder if there is a more traditional way of handling this problem.

file: `bootstrap-only.less`

```
.bootstrap {
  @import 'bootstrap.css'
}
```

file: `bootstrap-only.css`

```
.bootstrap .container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

file: `page.html`

```
<style>
  .container { width: 20px; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-only.css">

<div class="not-bootstrap">
  <div class="container">I am 20px</div>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap">
  <div class="container">I am 100%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try usig scooped css.Please do refer the following sample code.

```
<div>   
  <style scoped>
    @import "filename.css";
  </style>
  //your div with its children will come here
</div>
```

Comment: As cool as that sounds, the project needs to support old browsers :( Thank you for turning me on to that feature, i hadn't heard of it till now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your inline styles should not be affected by adding Bootstrap as inline styles take precedence over styles from external resources. The only elements that should be affected are the ones in the page that share class names with bootstrap classes.

You can try referencing the Bootstrap css before your own css and your stylesheet will take precedence over the Bootstrap css. Unfortunately this may add styles additional styles to some of your classes which that you didn't explicitly reference in your stylesheet and may still change the look of your page.

For those classes that exist in both bootstrap and your stylesheet it's probably best to just change the names of those classes in your stylesheet and page. A quick way to do this is to use "replace" search for the class name and replace it with the new class name most IDEs have a way to "replace all" so it's often just a bit of typing and a few clicks to change a bunch of styles.

Comment: Yes that is a better way of programming, but i'd rather not mess with the legacy code. I tried loading bootstrap first, but it changed all the input's styles for instance.  I updated my question with a decent solution for now, but i'm still curious on other ways to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Angular 2+, where you can simply create an component and us it anywhere irrespective of the page css. Basically it will create a shadow DOM and will not be accessible outside that component.